# React question about geofire and useEffect

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, react-native, geofire

I have a question about react, Although I don't have much experience. I'm trying to do a query with `geoFire` and get the location after that find the data in my database.

`Geofire` creates an event that I'm subscribed and send me the closest locations.

This moment I have a query with `geoFire` and with an `useEffect` I do update `data` in my state for caching the values.

When I update my state this action breaks `geofire` event and must start again from the beginning. So this is a problem? or is there a better solution?

method `getQuery`

```js
const firebaseRef: any = database().ref();
const geoFire = new GeoFire(firebaseRef);

  static getQuery(currentLocation: [number, number], radius: number): GeoQuery {
  return geoFire.query({
    center: currentLocation,
    radius,
  });
}
```

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';
import {GeoPosition, GeoError} from 'react-native-geolocation-service';
import {GeoQuery} from 'geofire';

import {getCurrentLocation, LocationInfo} from '../../util/geolocation';

import GeoFireService, {EVENT_TYPE} from './services/GeoFireService';
// import AdService from './services/AdService';

interface CurrentLocation {
  [key: string]: {
    location: [number, number];
    distance: number;
  };
}

const Ads = () => {
  const [locationInfo, setLocationInfo] = useState({
    latitude: 0,
    longitude: 0,
    altitude: 0,
    accuracy: 0,
  } as LocationInfo);
  const [query, setQuery]: [GeoQuery | null, Function] = useState(null);
  const [currentLocation, setCurrentLocation] = useState({} as CurrentLocation);

  // set the current location
  useEffect(() => {
    getCurrentLocation(
      (position: GeoPosition) => {
        const {latitude, longitude, accuracy, altitude} = position.coords;
        setLocationInfo({latitude, longitude, accuracy, altitude});
      },
      (err: GeoError) => {
        console.log(err);
      },
    );
  }, []);

  // set the event query
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const geoFireQuery = await GeoFireService.getQuery(
        [-34.5742746, -58.4744191],
        30,
      );
      setQuery(geoFireQuery);

      return () => geoFireQuery.cancel();
    })();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (query) {
      (query as GeoQuery).on(
        EVENT_TYPE.KEY_ENTERED,
        (key: string, location: [number, number], distance: number) => {
          console.log(key);
          if (!currentLocation[key]) {
            setCurrentLocation({
              ...currentLocation,
              [key]: {location, distance},
            });
          }
        },
      );
    }
  }, [query, currentLocation]);

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>
        Latitude: {locationInfo.latitude} Longitude: {locationInfo.longitude}
      </Text>

      {Object.keys(currentLocation).map((key: string) => (
        <Text key={key}>
          Ubicacion: {key}, Km: {currentLocation[key].distance.toFixed(2)}
        </Text>
      ))}
    </View>
  );
};

export default Ads;
```

This moment I have 3 location but this repeats too much. The console output should only show three locations

```js
[Sun Jun 07 2020 20:06:14.990]  LOG      1wr0cDenn4DmJ8S0xraG
[Sun Jun 07 2020 20:06:14.120]  LOG      58zvRXriUELSW96HprHh
[Sun Jun 07 2020 20:06:14.121]  LOG      58zvRXriUELSW96HprHh
[Sun Jun 07 2020 20:06:14.122]  LOG      58zvRXriUELSW96HprHh
[Sun Jun 07 2020 20:06:14.134]  LOG      58zvRXriUELSW96HprHh
[Sun Jun 07 2020 20:06:14.145]  LOG      1wr0cDenn4DmJ8S0xraG
[Sun Jun 07 2020 20:06:14.158]  LOG      2Y5DBEsPQ1eFosxoAimB
[Sun Jun 07 2020 20:06:14.159]  LOG      2Y5DBEsPQ1eFosxoAimB
[Sun Jun 07 2020 20:06:14.160]  LOG      2Y5DBEsPQ1eFosxoAimB
[Sun Jun 07 2020 20:06:14.174]  LOG      2Y5DBEsPQ1eFosxoAimB
[Sun Jun 07 2020 20:06:14.187]  LOG      1wr0cDenn4DmJ8S0xraG
[Sun Jun 07 2020 20:06:14.188]  LOG      58zvRXriUELSW96HprHh
[Sun Jun 07 2020 20:06:14.189]  LOG      2Y5DBEsPQ1eFosxoAimB
[Sun Jun 07 2020 20:06:14.198]  LOG      1wr0cDenn4DmJ8S0xraG
[Sun Jun 07 2020 20:06:14.199]  LOG      2Y5DBEsPQ1eFosxoAimB
[Sun Jun 07 2020 20:06:14.240]  LOG      2Y5DBEsPQ1eFosxoAimB
[Sun Jun 07 2020 20:06:14.286]  LOG      1wr0cDenn4DmJ8S0xraG
```

Comment: it seems like your useEffect that has `if (query)` is configured to run on every render (since there is no dependency array), and it seems like that's going to resubscribe to the `query.on` which gives you a new key, which you add to state, which triggers a rerender which runs the `if (query) ` useEffect again... etc. Do you want the last useEffect to run only once on mount maybe?

Comment: Hi @DonaldP, yes I want to run  the last useEffect only once but, already used it as componentDidMout and it does not work for me.  Because runs only once and it ok but React does not update the state with the new value. I used `[]` and `[query,  setCurrentLocation]` the last option is the same output

Comment: when you say "React does not update the state" do you mean that the `setCurrentLocation` call is not doing what you expect? It looks like it should update the array stored in state containing they keys.

Comment: Did you check my answer?

Comment: @DonaldP    Yes, the problems with this `[query, currentLocation]`  is that it calls the `on` event again. The output is the same.

Comment: This is solved here by @Pavlos Karalis
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62629902/react-useeffect-avoid-update-callback-in-every-update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62629902/react-useeffect-avoid-update-callback-in-every-update/62630330#62630330)

Answer (score 0):

You're last `useEffect` call is running on every render and it needs a dependency which is `query`. if you change your code like below you're good to go:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (query) {
      (query as GeoQuery).on(
        'key_entered',
        (key: string, location: [number, number], distance: number) => {
          if (!currentLocation.includes(key)) {
            console.log(key);
            setCurrentLocation([...currentLocation, key]);
          }
        },
      );
    }
  }, [query]); // <-- Add query as dependency
```

Comment: I tried. But it does not update my State `currentLocation`.  The output is correct and only shows 3 locations

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code snippet

```
import GeoFire from 'geofire';

const geoFire = new GeoFire(firebase.database().ref('locations'));

const query = geoFire.query({
  center: [37.7853, -122.4197],
  radius: 5.0
});

query.on('key_entered', (key, location, distance) => {
  firebase.database().ref('data/' + key).once('value', snapshot => {
    const data = snapshot.val();
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```